# preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/'

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I have tested and implemented regex in laravel but it show me the error. Please look into this

EmployerSignupRequest.php

```
'ephone'   => 'required|regex:/^[((\+)|0)[.\- ]?[0-9][.\- ]?[0-9][.\- ]?[0-9]+$/',
```

and i am getting this error.

preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found' in /var/www/html/jobma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:1370

when i run this in php, This is working fine

```
<?php
    $subject = "+91-9041742722";
    $pattern = '/^[((\+)|0)[.\- ]?[0-9][.\- ]?[0-9][.\- ]?[0-9]+$/';
    preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: Use `'ephone'   => array('required', 'regex:/^[((\+)|0)[.\- ]?[0-9][.\- ]?[0-9][.\- ]?[0-9]+$/'),` But I guess you wanted `^[+0][.\- ]?[0-9][.\- ]?[0-9][.\- ]?[0-9]+$`, right? You want to match either `0` or `+` at the beginning, then an optional delimiter, and the rest.

Comment: Could you please post the requirements for the pattern?

Comment: In addition to Wiktor's comment, there is another problem: `^[((\+)|0)[.\- ]?[0-9][.\- ]?[0-9][.\- ]?[0-9]+$` has an extraneous "[" immediately following the initial "^" anchor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing syntax here.You can use below pattern for your regular expression.

```
array('phone' => 'required', 'required|regex:/^\+?[^a-zA-Z]{5,}$/');
```

Comment: This `/^[((\+)|0)[.\- ]?[0-9][.\- ]?[0-9][.\- ]?[0-9]+$/` pattern is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for correcting. i have made few changes in regular exp.

Comment: You just steal my suggestions. "Try this", "this should work", and no explanations why that should work. No syntax is "missing" here, it is just incorrect.

Comment: That's not a good phrasing like you stole from docs. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: my apology , i am doing some changes in my post actually i just wanted to correct the validation syntax for laraval.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to use an array because your pattern contains a pipe. See [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-regex):

> When using the `regex` pattern, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

Also, your pattern starts with `[((\+)|0)[.\- ]?` optional character class that matches either `(` or `+`, `)`, `|`, `0`, `[`, `-`, or space.  I think you want to match either a `0` or a `+` optionally followed by a delimiter, so replace it with `[0+][.\- ]`.

Use

```
'ephone' => ['required', 'regex:/^[0+][.\- ]?[0-9][.\- ]?[0-9][.\- ]?[0-9]+$/'],
```

If the `+` or `0` are to be optional, add `?` after `[0+]` (this matches either a `0` or a literal `+`, and if you add a `?` after it, this will be optional, matching 1 or 0 occurrences of the pattern).

You can further test the regex at [the regex101.com online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/bO1aM2/1).